# How to store and retrieve Shopping Cart items in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a shopping cart for an e-commerce website and want to store the products in the browser localstorage.

I've implemented the following functions into my code for adding and retrieving products

addToCart() is the function that launches each time the Add to Cart button is pressed.
addProduct() adds each product to the cartList.
getProductsFromLocalStorage() retrieves the products from the localStorage and adds the products to the cartList.

```
  function addToCart(trigger) {
    var cartIsEmpty = cartWrapper.hasClass('empty');
    //get localstorage cart product list
    getProductsFromLocalStorage();
    //update cart product list
    addProduct();
    //update number of items
    updateCartCount(cartIsEmpty);
    //update total price
    updateCartTotal(trigger.data('price'), true);
    //show cart
    cartWrapper.removeClass('empty');
  }

  function addProduct() {

    productId = productId + 1;
    var productName = document.getElementById('reebok').innerHTML;
    var productPrice = document.getElementById('p_price').getAttribute('data- value');
    var image = document.getElementById("main_img").src;
    var productSize = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var productColor = document.getElementById('color').value;
    value = parseFloat(productPrice).toFixed(2);

    var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="'+ image +'" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">' + productName + '</a></h3><span class="price">'+ productPrice +'</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><a class="delete-item">'+ productSize +'</a><a class="delete-item">'+ productColor +'</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-' + productId + '">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-' + productId + '" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>');

    cartList.append(productAdded);

    let products = [{'productId' : productId + 1, image : image, name : productName, price: productPrice, size: productSize, color: productColor}];

    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));

  }

  function getProductsFromLocalStorage() {
    const cs = localStorage.getItem('products');
    if (cs === null) {
      addProduct();
    } else {
      $.each(cs.products, function(key, value) {
        cartList.prepend($('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="'+ value.image +'" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">' + value.name + '</a></h3><span class="price">${value.price}</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><a class="delete-item">' + value.size + '</a><a class="delete-item">' + value.color + '</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-' + value.productId + '">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-' + value.productId + '" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>'));
      });
    }
  }
```

I've now got the issue of not being able to retrieve the cart items from the local storage and add them to the cart with new items. This means the shopping cart items are saved in storage but I see a blank cart when I attempt to add new items as below:

[Screenshot of Shopping Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTsYv.png)

The demo of this code is at https://codyhouse.co/demo/add-to-cart-interaction/index.html.

Thanks for any assistance,

James.

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hello Vinit, I've added some more information to my question. It seems I can't get the items back from the local storage. The code for my functions are updated in the question above. Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You are storing the products in localstorage as JSON string but while rereiving, you are not parsing the products. What you should do is `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/rwv9hk1z/6/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use browser's localstorage for it.

In your function `addProduct`, you should add array of products to a local storage item say `products`; like so:

```
function addProduct(){
    let products = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('products')){
        products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    }
    products.push({'productId' : productId + 1, image : '<imageLink>'});
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
}
```

If you want to remove product, you can do it like so:

```
function removeProduct(productId){

    // Your logic for your app.

    // strore products in local storage

    let storageProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    let products = storageProducts.filter(product => product.productId !== productId );
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
}
```

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/rwv9hk1z/1/) for working demo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vinit, I've updated my code to set the local storage with an array of my products. Would I use localStorage.get to retrieve the contents of the localstorage variable when the page is refreshed? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. `localStorage.getItem('<whatever_the_name>')`.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle demo too, I didn't know I can check the Application tab in the dev tools to see the function in action.  Issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

Adding product in local storage and retrieve from state

```
 export const addItemToCart = (id, quantity) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
            type: ADD_TO_CART,
            payload: {
                product: data.product.id,
                name: data.product.name
            }
        })
    
        
    
        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this javascript package for storing any kind of data in the browser's indexDB that way the data persists after reload. [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage)

Comment: Why to use a custom library when there is browser localStorage available? Please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Localstorage only allows you to store strings, I am assuming your cart is an object. localforage is good package to enable you store objects.

Comment: Sure. You can store objects in the form of JSON strings though.

Comment: Localforage is optimized to use other mediums like indexDB rather than localstorage in storing data, based on the type of data you pass to it. each of these medium (indexDB, WebSQL, and localstorage) have their advantages

Comment: Hello Spankie, I'm actually trying to store the products in the browser localStorage like Vinit said.