# How do I save objects that I push into an array, then display them using local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

I am trying to make a simple shopping cart using just html and javascript. I have an empty array as my cart and I have an object called product1. I have a click event where it pushes the object name and price into the array, then displays it using innerHTML. I want to know how can I save the items in the cart when I refresh the page using local storage?

```
Here is my javascript code.

var cart = [];

var product1 = {
    name: "product1",
    price: 90.00
};

document.getElementById("cart-button").addEventListener("click", addToCart);

function addToCart() {
    cart.push(product1.name + "<br />" + product1.price);
    document.getElementById("cart-contents").innerHTML = cart;
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('cart-contents', cart)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve Shopping Cart items in localstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328748/how-to-store-and-retrieve-shopping-cart-items-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save it in localStorage at the time you add the items in the cart.
On reload, the cart variable loads the cart from the localStorage. If there is no localStorage var cart it gets an empty array.

```js
var cart =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

var product1 = {
    name: "product1",
    price: 90.00
};

document.getElementById("cart-button").addEventListener("click", addToCart);

function addToCart() {
    cart.push(product1.name + "<br />" + product1.price);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    document.getElementById("cart-contents").innerHTML = cart;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store you cart as a json string, when you update it. 
You can parse it on load using `JSON.parse()`

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

var product1 = {
    name: "product1",
    price: 90.00
};

document.getElementById("cart-button").addEventListener("click", addToCart);

function addToCart() {
    cart.push(product1.name + "<br />" + product1.price);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', cart);
    document.getElementById("cart-contents").innerHTML = cart;
}
```